# Is it possible to use Entity Generator to create a unidirectional one-to-one relationship with User default entity?

Tags: jhipster

I'm trying to use entity generator to create a unidirectional one-to-one relationship between default User entity and a new entity:

```
entity User
entity Passport

relationship OneToOne {
  User{passport} to Passport
}
```

But I am getting an error message:

```
➔ yo jhipster:entity User
Error jhipster:entity User

ERROR! The table name cannot contain a PostgreSQL reserved keyword
```

OK, I know the error. But in JHipster case I can't change the tables name.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I think it just says it in your face, you need to name your "User" differently since it is a reserved word in Postgres.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev i edited the question. ty

Comment: But why can't you change your class name?

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev because I am using [JHipster](https://jhipster.github.io/). And User is an entity generated by the framework. This already have a lot of features using this entity. I think it is possible to change the entity name, but will spend a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JHipster currently (v4.10) **creates a entity User by default**, with basics attributes, so u cant use this name again, because this is in use, reserved keyword. You can only use this in relations. [Managing relationships JHipster](http://www.jhipster.tech/managing-relationships/)

So u can try someone of this alternatives:

- Use other name for your entity *User*, for example *Citizen*.

  ```
  entity Citizen
  entity Passport

  relationship OneToOne {
    Citizen{passport} to Passport
  }
  ```
- Create only the relation to User entity, (not to be confused with creating the entity).

  ```
  entity Passport

  relationship OneToOne {
    Passport{User} to User
  }
  ```

I hope I helped you, regards.